# Android Studio How to fix cannot create class-file error?

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, tesseract

I am following the steps mentioned here: https://priyankvex.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/how-to-build-tesseract-ocr-library-for-android-studio/

Step 3 tells to copy and paste the `tess-two` folder to my Project but when I paste, I get an error stating `Cannot create class-file` and none of my `.java' files get copied.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is **but it works, if you copy the folder directly into the project folder** instead of copying through the Android Studio.

Maybe for some reason the files are not copied in the **Android Studio**.

Answer (score 0):

It is because some .class files are included in your copy files.
Some IDE will not include .class file in project and show this tips.